# Using same id (not active one)

Tags: filemaker

I've got an issue with a button.

I've got clients, and these all have a number ( Clients:: ClientID). Now I want to make a button in another form and send the active clientID to another application which will use this clientID to display information in that application about that client.

Now I've made a button with the open URL which contains following code snippet:

```
"http://localhost:12345/showClientFile?clientid=" &  Clients::ClientID
```

When I click the button in viewlayout, the application always (no matter which record I'm in) the same clientID and not the clientID from the record that I'm in. When I check the URL in the browser, it is also that same id constantly. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "viewlayout" or "a button in another form". In order for what you described to work, you (and your button) need to be on a layout of the `Clients` TO.

Comment: I'm indeed on a layout of another TO, is there any way to put this value into this TO?

viewlayout is just the name of the normal view (not the edit view :p )and form is a name I use for the different TO's. I'm not really specialized in this filemaker syntax. I'm sorry for this ;-)

Comment: If you're on a layout of another TO, then how can you tell which client is the one you want? -- P.S. I recommend you post this on one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform, where your problem can be discussed, if necessary with files attached. SO is strictly a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a layout that isn't linked to the `Clients` table occurrence, then there must be a relationship from whichever TO your layout is linked to to the `Clients` table. Otherwise you wouldn't see any value for `Clients::ClientID`.

You say you want to send the "active clientID". How do you, or the system, know what the active clientID is? Is it stored in a global variable, as in `$$_ACTIVE_CLIENT_ID`, or perhaps a global field, `Clients::g_active_client_id`? When you can say to yourself, "When I want to know what the active client ID is, I look *here*," then you know what will need to be done to edit the URL calculation.

```
"http://localhost:12345/showClientFile?clientid=" & $$_ACTIVE_CLIENT_ID
```